# Login through twitter failiing as "unauthorized" in OSQA

Tags: python, twitter, osqa

I have installed OSQA on a site hosted on hostgator. The login functionality is working for google, yahoo and facebook, but when I click on twitter's icon it's generating an exception. I have already added the twitter consumer key and the twitter consumer secret through the admin interface. The exception I am getting is:

```
HTTPError at /account/twitter/signin/

HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized


Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://mydomain/account/twitter/signin/?validate_email=yes
Exception Type:     HTTPError
Exception Value:    HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.4/urllib2.py in http_error_default, line 480
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.4.3
```

I am unable to trace out the reason for the same.

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the earlier application created in twitter and created a new one. Added the new keys through administration panel and it resolved my issue.But i am still unable to figure out what caused problem in my earlier application?